# What is "Temp Uploads Location" in Craft 3.2.10

Tags: assets, volumes

In Craft (Solo) 3.2.10, In Settings > Assets > Asset Settings, there's a field called "Temp Uploads Location". I do see images in mine that I intended to go into the system, but not into there.

What is that feature for?

Comment: Which version of Craft are you on?

Comment: @LindseyD Just updated. It’s Craft 3.

Comment: What is the full version number? Craft 3.3 was just released today.

Comment: Ah, it's Craft Solo 3.2.10.

Comment: Great, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That setting is basically saying, "where do you want your Assets to be stored *while the related Entry is still being processed?*"

[image: Asset Settings]

Take a practical example... You are editing an Entry, and want to upload an Asset to a specific field in your entry. Click-click-click, you've added the Asset. But **until you've saved the Entry**, this will be considered a temporary Asset. After all, if you abandon your changes to the Entry, is it still worth saving the newly uploaded Asset?

"In the local temp folder" will drop those temporary assets into the Temporary Assets folder. That folder is exactly what it says... a temporary location for uploaded assets. Once you've properly saved your Entry, the new Asset will be moved to the appropriate location.

[image: Temporary Assets]

It's worth noting, Assets stored in the Temporary Assets folder **are real assets**. You may not have a front-end path to reach them, but by all other measures they are real Assets as far as Craft is concerned.

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. Silly that there was nothing official about it coming up from searches. Thanks!